Восстановление баз данных при удалении MySQL с компьютера. Содержимое папки C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data было сохранено
Такая ситуация, удалял MySQL с компьютера, при этом сохранил папку C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data  отдельно на диске, там находятся мои учебные базы данных. Думал после переустановки MySQL вернуть их на место и пользоваться дальше. Но сделать так не получается, после возвращения базы не видны в Workbench.
Подскажите, можно ли их как то вернуть, ведь все файлы баз данных сохранены
Большое спасибо!

Нашел видео где сказано, что таким способом тоже можно сохранять/восстанавливать базы данных, но почему то не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Ответ найден -- перед тем как копировать/заменить содержимое папки C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data на сохраненную за ранее папку нужно в Службах остановить MySQL80. После копирования запустить обратно. Наслаждаемся базами данных
